# Integrate wordpress in Ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a RoR application in my machine.Now they want to integrate a wordpress blog.
So my RoR application is running at `localhost:3000`,I want to work wordpress as `localhost:3000/blog`.

I changed the document root of apache and placed it on /rorapp/public. 
Now it is working as localhost/blog But i want to do as localhost:3000/blog.

Pls help me.

Comment: This may be useful http://www.igvita.com/2007/07/04/integrating-wordpress-and-rails/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your apache config file to listen on :3000 it should be fine.

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
DocumentRoot "D:/root/to/site/"
ServerName localhost

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```